# Swift/iOS: Hide TabBar when Tab Bar Item is touched

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitabbarcontroller, tabbar

im new to iOS programming and I would appreciate your help!

I have a tab bar with several items. 
When a specific tab bar item is touched, I want the tab bar to be hidden until the user leaves the triggered view through touching a cancel button.

Similar to: `self.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = true`, but not only when a view controller is pushed onto a navigation stack.

Alternatively, I want to leave the bar control when this specific tab bar item is touched and go back to it when the cancel button is touched.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could hide the tab bar in the triggered view controller's `viewWillAppear` method:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    // without animation
    tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = true

    // with animation
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25, animations: {
        self.tabBarController?.tabBar.alpha = 0
    }) { _ in
        self.tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = true
    }
}
```

When you want to show the tab bar again simply set its `isHidden` property to false (with an optional animation).

Comment: Perfect, thank you!